# Getting data out of table using Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, slice

I'm trying to pull a list of items from a shopping cart (a table) and drop it into a WP email form. This code (almost) works - that is, I can see all of the items in the log console. But only the last item shows up in the text area of the form. So, if there's 1 item in the shopping cart, it drops into the textarea box. However if there are 2 items, the second item shows up and the first item doesn't. But I can see both items in the console log.

I'm completely lost by what's happening with the array(s). I've tried, join, concat, and converting the 'allProducts' variable to a string. Nothing changes the output.  It seems like it should be simple.

I can't figure out how to combine the output so that everything drops into the textarea field of the form.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

```
function confirmProducts() {
    var product = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("cart").getElementsByClassName("cartLink"));
    var quantity = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById("cart").getElementsByClaseName("iquantity"));

    for (var i in product, quantity){
        var products = product[i].innerHTML;
        var quantities = quantity[i].value;
        var allProducts = quantities + " " + products;
        document.SUPPLY_PURCHASE.yourorder.value = allProducts ;
        console.log(allProducts);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.SUPPLY_PURCHASE.yourorder.value = allProducts;
```

You are overriding the previous value of the text field here. You can use

```
document.SUPPLY_PURCHASE.yourorder.value += allProducts;
```

This will add each product to the text field. You probably want to add newlines in between the products.

```
document.SUPPLY_PURCHASE.yourorder.value += allProducts + "\n";
```

`console.log` does just write to the console and old log entries are not overridden. That is why you can see all products in the console.

---

There are a few other problems with your code. `product, quantity` is the same as just `quantity`. There is no special syntax for iterating over multiple arrays using a `for in` loop. The comma you use here is just a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).
Also `for in` is not the optimal loop for iterating over an array.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  So, would [code]    var n = product.length;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++){'[/code]  be a better way to loop?

Comment: Sorry, I'm  new. . . I couldn't figure out how to add code to a comment. (The above does work too).

Comment: `var n = product.length`  then `for (var i = 0; i>n; i++) {`

Comment: Yes  `for (var i = 0; i < product.length; i++)` would be better. The `for in` loop has some problems. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/6430127

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @kayphoonstar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the textarea in the loop. Capture your products in a separate variable and set textarea at the end of your loop. You will need a new line to see the list in a sensible way.

```
var productList = "";

for (var i in product, quantity){
var products = product[i].innerHTML;
var quantities = quantity[i].value;
var allProducts = quantities + " " + products + "\r\n";
productList += allProducts;
console.log(allProducts);
}

document.SUPPLY_PURCHASE.yourorder.value = productList ;
```

Comment: Thank you! I confuse myself very quickly with loops.